# Multiple custom views in a single scene in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

Requirement: I have a main view. On tap of a button in the main view, a small custom view should appear as an overlay on the main view.

Can i design both the views in a single scene?

Snapshot of my Xcode Scene: 
http://tinypic.com/r/sos8kh/9

Will this work?

Or what is the use of adding a view at that place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work, when you click the button just use an iboutlet to make it visible if you have any other problems just let me know il be happy to try and help :)

Comment: It worked... But i still wonder, how is that getting linked? How is the IBOutlet defined at a top level maps to a custom view outside that hierarchy?

Comment: I think its because your custom view is still technically in the view controller. If this answer helped at all please mark it as the correct answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the entryView inside the view.
You can make it hidden until the user press the button.